# Printing the timestamp milliseconds in R does not work

Tags: r

I have an application that logs some info in R. I am using `logging` library for that. My problem is that the `timestamp` has no milliseconds, and I get not always the good order of the logs. In the logging file, R puts the logs in the right order, but I use `logstash` and `es` for having the history and for monitoring. Because the timestamp I got not the right order of the logs, so I would like to add milliseconds.

I have tried to use `strptime` and `%OS(n)`, but it seems not to work. If I add the `%OS`, I get `NA` even for simple things:

```
strptime(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%OS")
```

I have seen that there are more posts like this, but no answer, so I am posting it here, too.

I have to say that I use R 3.2.0 under Linux Ubuntu 14.04. How to solve it? How to have milliseconds in `timestamp`?

---

OK, after using `strftime`, I am getting the milliseconds, but it seems that they are always 0.

I have a log formater:

```
logFormatter <- function(record) {
  sprintf('Application(%s) %s [%s] [] %s - %s', format(as.hexmode(Sys.getpid()), width = 8), record$levelname, strftime(record$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS3"), record$logger, record$msg)
}
```

I have added the logger:

```
addHandler(writeToFile, logger = "MyLogger", file = "/var/log/Application/logs.log", level = 'INFO', formatter = logFormatter)
```

and I log like this:

```
loginfo("some info X", logger = MyLogger)
```

but the output seems to be always at the beginning of the second:

```
Application(000018f3) INFO [2015-09-21T11:45:56.000] [] some info 1
Application(000018f3) INFO [2015-09-21T11:45:58.000] [] some info 2
Application(000018f3) INFO [2015-09-21T11:45:58.000] [] some info 3
Application(000018f3) INFO [2015-09-21T11:45:58.000] [] some info 4
Application(000018f3) INFO [2015-09-21T11:45:59.000] [] some info 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain millisecond information it is usually helpful to set

```
options(digits.secs = 3)
```

This will give, for instance

```
> strptime(Sys.time(), format =  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2015-09-21 11:52:09.787 CEST"
```

Maybe this helps in your case.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `strftime` instead of `strptime`, and there is an easy way to show milliseconds as follows:

```
strftime(Sys.time(), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
```

which will output

```
[1] "2015-09-21 10:32:58.669559"
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: er... nope, my problem seems to be the `record$timestamp`, it is always `HH:MM:SS.000` How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you write an example of the `record$timestamp`?